# How to sort the loaded XML data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, sorting

In my application, I have an `XML` file that connects to different API and gathers information. Then in a `div`, it shows the fetched information. 
I do it successfully, but the issue is, the `XML` will not load if element one by one. It loads data in parallel, so the `div`s it creates are not in the right order like how they are in the `xml` file.

Here is a **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e0zs4v1k/)** that get some data from local, SoundCloud, Spotify and iTunes.

And this is the [**`XML` file**](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33538012/text.xml) it is loading from:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33538012/text.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: parse,
  error: function() {
    alert("Error");
  }
});

function parse(document) {
  var inc = 1;

  $(document).find("track").each(function() {
    var rowNum = inc;
    var trackType = $(this).find('type').text();
    var trackTitle = $(this).find('title').text();
    var soundcloud_url = $(this).find('soundcloud_url').text();
    var spotify_track_uri = $(this).find('spotify_track_uri').text();
    var itunes_id = $(this).find('itunes_id').text();
    
    if (trackType == "audio") {
      inc = inc + 1;
      $(".playlist").append("<div id='" + rowNum + "' >" + rowNum + " " + trackTitle + "</div>");
      
    } else if (trackType == "soundcloud") {
      inc = inc + 1;
      SC.initialize({
        client_id: "b8f06bbb8e4e9e201f9e6e46001c3acb"
      });
      SC.resolve(soundcloud_url).then(function(sound) {
        trackTitle = sound.title;
        $(".playlist").append("<div id='" + rowNum + "' >" + rowNum + " " + trackTitle + "</div>");
      });
      
    } else if (trackType == "spotify") {
      inc = inc + 1;
      var spotifyLink = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/" + spotify_track_uri;
      $.getJSON(spotifyLink, function(data) {
        trackTitle = data.name;
        $(".playlist").append("<div id='" + rowNum + "' >" + rowNum + " " + trackTitle + "</div>");
      });
      
    } else if (trackType == "itunes") {
      inc = inc + 1;
      var iTuensLink = "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=" + itunes_id + "&callback=?";
      $.getJSON(iTuensLink, function(data) {
        trackTitle = data.results[0].trackName;
        $(".playlist").append("<div id='" + rowNum + "' >" + rowNum + " " + trackTitle + "</div>");
      })
    }
    
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="playlist"></div>
```

If you look at the result of the code, the the number next to each row shows the order in the original `XML` file, but they are not loaded exactly one after each other.

Any way to sort the loaded files just like how they are written in the `XML` file?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you're getting the XML in proper order, it's the requests you make for each online item that don't take the same time. `dan` and `Sasy` will come up first each time because you don't make such request

Comment: @Aaron that's right. each online item has its one response time and that makes the `div`s unsorted. I need a way to sort them. Maybe after all data is gathered.

Comment: this requires an array of promises to be created and only when they are all resolved insert the data

Comment: @charlietfl Well it would be great if you post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use deffered object which are an extension of promise and can resolve it self.So they can act as a trigger when used with resolve

Crate an array that would hold our deffered objects note that order is important therefore numeric array is used
Just create a deffered

```
var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
```

Define what should be done on

```
dfd.then(function(){
  $(".playlist").append("<div id='" + rowNum + "' >" + rowNum + " " + trackTitle + "</div>");
  })
```

Finally push it on our array

```
  x.push(dfd)
```

After all api calls are over just call `resolve` on each

```
$.each(x, function(){
    this.resolve(); //then callback gets called one by one on each deffered 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sanddune/rr7tord6/

You might want to have some mechanism to detect when the slowest call finishes and then call resolve

EDIT:

The latency of individual api varies greatly across geographies for example for me soundcloud was the most "laggy" so it ended up last but for someone else itunes may be the last to finish this is due to many variables like distance from server,ISP,throttling etc. so clearly you can never rely on "last man standing " approach so i could only suggest that use some sort of counter like this to track how many request are outstanding

First get total no. of nodes (inn xml) that have an api involved say you have just soundcloud and shopify so now `total = 2` ; `count = 0`

so when the api request yields increment it by one like

```
$.getJSON(spotifyLink, function(data) {
    trackTitle = data.name;
    alert('shopify loaded'); 
    count++;check();
});
```

or

```
SC.resolve(soundcloud_url).then(function(sound) {
    trackTitle = sound.title;
    alert('soundcloud loaded'); 
    count++;check();
});
```

note that you need to increment on even failed api request (which may result from bad parameter etc.)

call a check function that will check if count == total on every success/fail part of api request

```
function check(){
  if(count==total)
  alert('all api request finished');
  //resolve all deffereds
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works perfectly. Only issue is that the process is done after the button is pressed, is it possible to do that bit kinda automatically, like as soon as the plugin loads? Thank again

Comment: Thank you for your quality answer. Indeed +1 and approving it as an answer is not enough for appreciation.